# apt broken install/update/remove causes input/output error for linux-image package

Tags: apt, package-management, mate

I can't install/update/remove anything because of this error, nor does google return anything specifically for linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic (It does for other things, but I am not sure what to touch as I am not an advanced user)

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic': Input/output error
```

I just tried to `apt-get remove apt` (then I was going to follow answer https://askubuntu.com/a/626523/397432) but the result is the same error.

How do I fix this?

I am trying to avoid reinstalling the system and everything on it

I'm using Ubuntu MATE 16.04

**Further tests advised by N0rbert**

```
ls -al /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 82416 Dec 18  2017 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic.list


head -n5 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic.list
/.
/lib
/lib/firmware
/lib/firmware/4.10.0-42-generic
/lib/firmware/4.10.0-42-generic/tigon
```

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/140636) might help.

Comment: Please run forced filesystem check on the root filesystem with `sudo touch /forcefsck` and reboot and wait it to finish. Then please add output of `ls -al /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic.list`, `head -n5 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic.list` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert I did what you said and added it to the question

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138154/apt-broken-install-update-remove-causes-fatal-error-about-linux-image?noredirect=1#comment1886161_1138154 @Kulfy's answer solved it!