# Removed apt as package manager

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, nala

[Nala](https://gitlab.com/volian/nala) is a recently-introduced package manager which also uses `dpkg` for managing packages in Ubuntu.
I installed `nala` and I'm getting a very decent experience.

Now, I wanted to remove `apt` from my system, so that only one package manager (`nala`) remains on it.

I tried:

```
nala remove apt --remove-essentials
```

but after this command ran successfully, I lost both `apt` and `nala`.

On `nala update` I am getting:

```
bash: /usr/bin/nala: No such file or directory
```

Comment: "Nala is a front-end for libapt-pkg. Specifically we interface using the python-apt api.
Especially for newer users it can be hard to understand what apt is trying to do when installing or upgrading.
**We aim to solve this by not showing some redundant messages, formatting the packages better, and using color to
show specifically what will happen with a package during install, removal, or an upgrade.**" I find very ironic that you like nala which is a tool that tries to solve a human problem with technology and your question proves that, as expected, it fails badly: users don't read.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You made a rather big mistake, in taking for granted that `nala` doesn't need `apt` - it does.

This is completely evident by running `apt depends nala`, showing `nala`'s dependencies.

```
nala
  Depends: python3-anyio
  Depends: python3-httpx
  Depends: python3-pexpect
  Depends: python3-rich
  Depends: python3-tomli
  Depends: python3-typer
  Depends: python3-typing-extensions
  Depends: <python3:any>
    python3
  Depends: apt
  Depends: python3-apt
  Depends: python3-debian
  Recommends: python3-socksio
```

So `nala` will not function without `apt`.

If you had carefully read the output of the command `nala remove apt --remove-essentials`, you would most likely see that it was about to remove the `nala` package itself. Hence, it's important to review what the command is about to do, especially when you run the command with the `--remove-essentials` option (an option that can potentially break the system).

It's generally a good idea to do a `--dry-run` before removing critical packages, or running with `--remove-essentials` - and ironically, this is an option that only `apt` supports, but `nala` does not (yet).

Also, you didn't state why you suddenly wanted to remove `apt`, but I have some guesses:

- *You would like to "clean up" your packages.*

  This is sometimes a good idea, but not when you're not sure of the consequences. Also, if you had read the first part of the `nala` [readme](https://gitlab.com/volian/nala/-/blob/main/README.rst):

  > Nala is a front-end for `libapt-pkg`. Specifically we interface using the `python-apt` api.

  Or from the package info `apt show nala`:

  > Commandline frontend for the APT package manager

  This should have given you a hint that it's dependent on `apt.`
- *You're satisfied with the performance of `nala` for common tasks, and thus don't need `apt`.*

  You may *think* this is the case, but I'd argue it's not. `nala` is software in a development stage, while `apt` has existed for 30 years. Also, while `nala` provides the most common functionality of `apt`, it can't do any of the more advanced stuff, which you suddenly might need (like `--dry-run`) - and often when you least expect it. So for daily tasks `nala` might be OK - but it can probably never replace the full `apt` package.

Now to restore `apt` to your system after you have removed it, please see [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626504/apt-get-removed-how-to-reinstall-it). The file `/var/log/apt/history.log` should actually contain a list of all the packages that were removed, which you have to reinstall manually.

What you basically have to do is find the appropriate version of `apt` ([example for Jammy](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/apt)) for your system *and all it's dependent packages*, and install these manually with `dpkg` (since you removed the only package manager that can actually handle dependencies for you).

Comment: Thank you for your attention, and providing me with bunch of knowledge on the basis of nala.

Comment: You're welcome. And I sincerely hope you learned something from this - good luck!

Comment: I would add to the answer that probably Nala informed OP that the command was about to remove the package `nala`, too, as one of its dependencies was not satisfied. And OP should have reviewed the output carefully before confirming, especially since they used the option `--remove-essentials` knowing the risk that it could break the system.